# Android Pagerview as circular menu

Tags: android, fragment, android-viewpager

I have in my code used standard `PagerView` (`FragmentPagerAdapter`) but because standard behavior is moving just from first to last page and I didn't find solutions to change it to circular menu (jump to first page after swipe on last), I hope that someone has already solved this and wants share his experiences ...